# how to set display member to a concatenated expression? datasource is linq query

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation, member

i'm trying to set the display member of my listbox to a concatenated value from a linq query:

```
var query =
     from a in db.Customers
     select a;

listBox1.DataSouce = query;
```

I was hoping to be able to set the display member by doing something like this:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "FirstName" + "LastName";
```

but obviously that doesn't work.

how do i do this? I guess the tricky part is the fact that the datasource is a linq query result object. But its indexable so there's gotta be some way.

Comment: What kind of LINQ? LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out by accident:

```
var query =
                from a in db.LUT_Employees
                where a.position == "Supervisor" && a.department == "Production"
                select new { a, Names = a.lastName + ", " + a.firstName };

            cboProductionSupervisor.DataSource = query;
            cboProductionSupervisor.DisplayMember = "Names";
```

basically what I did was create a new field on the fly just like you would in sql. then use that as the display member

Comment: I Bet that this code wont give you the desired output because your Datasource will be empty ie the query is not yet executed.

Comment: You have actually changed your code here though, because you no longer have an IEnumerable<Customer> you have an IEnumerable<AnonymousType>. So if you had any other bindings or code that expected that result to be of type customer, you would need to update them aswell.

Comment: True chris. This does complicate things and im still learning how to deal with these instances. But for basic functions like populating a listbox or combobox and assigning the valuemember to like a primary key or whatever, this seems to work pretty straightforward. Picking apart the anonymous datasource is kinda confusing in other scenarios. still learning though.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Customer class that you either wrote yourself or is genertaed but extendable, then the best method in my opinion is to add a new property to it

```
namespace SameNameSpaceAsGeneratedCustomerClass {
  public partial class Customer {
    public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
  }
}
```

If you are unable to do this, then you will need to look at creating a ValueConverter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: oh hey, i was just on your blog today reading up on some linq stuff. I'm looking at that link now. For this attempt, the class is actually just the class thats created for the table through the datacontext.

Comment: Which data access technology are you using. Linq2Sql and EF generate their classes as partial, so you can still extend them and add extra properties.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to include the code you will need for extending the generated Customer class. The only thing you need to find out is which namespace the Customer class is created in. It should match the folder your Linq2Sql defintion file is in.

Answer (score 0):

AT first i have to tell you that LINQ query wont execute by itself so if you are writing the above query ie

```
var query =
     from a in db.Customers
     select a;

listBox1.DataSouce = query;
```

you wont get the desired output.

for that modify the query to

```
   var query =  (from a in db.Customers select new{Name = a.FirstName + a.LastName, OtherDetails = a.OtherDetails}).ToList();

listBox1.DataSouce = query;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i placed these in the constructor so they execute when the comboboxes instantiate.